# How to stop modal from going to top of screen on button click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am having a persistent issue regarding [jquery modals](https://github.com/kylefox/jquery-modal). Whenever I click on the button with the name test, the modal does show up as I want it to do but it goes to the very top of the screen. Here is the primary code:

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/style.css">
    <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/devicons/devicon@v2.15.1/devicon.min.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/jquery/jquery-modal-master/jquery.modal.min.css" ></link>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.2/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
    <title>Local Portfolio</title>
</head>

<body>

<div class="card">
                <div class="info">
                    <h1>Java Paint</h1>
                    <img src="imgs/java_paint.png" alt="Java Paint">
                    <a href="#java_paint">More Information</a>
                    <button id = "java_paint_modal" type="button">Test</button>
                </div>
</div>


 <form id="java_paint" class="modal">
        <h2>About</h2>
        <p>
            A painting app programmed in Java using the Swing Library and Eclipse IDE. Allows the user to draw with a size adjustable pencil as well as changing the its color,
            picking a color from the screen and storing it for later use via the rectangle icon in the menu, erase contents as well as drawing a stroke adjustable line and with more features to come in the forseeable future
        </p> 
    </form>
</body>
```

script.js:

```js
$(document).on('click','#java_paint_modal', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("greetings")
    $("#java_paint").modal();
});
```

Keep in mind that i intially used an anchor tag but even thought i switched to a button, it still goes to the top of the screen

I am running this on the Opera GX browser incase it could be a browser issue

To see the issue in action, here is the [repo](https://github.com/m-zurkiyeh/Portfolio) and the [website](https://m-zurkiyeh.github.io/Portfolio/)